# Race condition scenario

Tags: c, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a question regarding a race condition scenario. The question:

> Consider the following two threads, to be run concurrently in a shared
>   memory (all variables are shared between the two threads).

```
Thread A 
for i = 1 to 5 do 
  x = x + 1;

Thread B 
for j = 1 to 5 do
  x = x + 1;
```

> Assuming a single-processor system, that load and store are atomic,
>   that x is initialized to 0, and that x must be loaded into a register
>   before being incremented (and stored back to memory afterwards), what
>   are all the possible values for x after both threads have completed?

Now the answer is 2:10 inclusive. I understand the results of 5:10, but how could x be 2, 3 or 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence to get x = 2:

```
Thread 2 read // Reg_2 = 0
Thread 1 read/write 4 times // x = 4
Thread 2 write // * Reg_2 = 0 --> x = 1
Thread 1 read // Reg_1 = 1
Thread 2 read/write 4 times // x = 5
Thread 1 write // Reg_1 = 1 --> x = 2
```

Depending on how many write thread 2 does before you preempt at the step marked with *, you will get the result for 3 and 4.

Comment: hi @nhahtdh I dont understand the logic you have applied. Kindly give some links to understand the underlaying logic. Also how does Thread 2 read/write 4 times, while Thread 1 is reading once. Could you please help me

Comment: @rakeshNS: You know that x = x + 1 involves read value of x to register, then (do calculation, and) write the new value to memory representing variable x (read precedes write). Total number of read/write for both threads are 5. The context switch between threads preserves value in the registers for each thread, but since location of x in memory is the same for both threads, problem happens when the threads are switch out between read/write.